# JSF Spring Hibernate project structure

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, project

I want to develop a project using with `JSF`, `Spring`, `Hibernate` technologies. I don't know how my project structure should be. Interfaces, implements, managedBeans, models, services, dao and goes on.

Is it possible you to guide me about this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Search for sample JEE projects from Reza Rahman and Adam Bien - they are JEE Evangelists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [JSF + Spring + Hibernate](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/) might be useful for you. Just follow all the procedures correctly and you will get what you want. Before I had tried it before. Or just download it's Source Code which you can find at the bottom.

Comment: thanks, I'm also interested in other structes as well